# python unable to access suds methods

Tags: python, linux, api, soap, suds

I am trying to access the SOAP api using SUDS in python

```
from suds.client import Client
def initialize():
    url = 'http://uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.com/wewewe/WsNBI?wsdl'
    username = 'xxxxx'
    password = 'ppppppp'
    client = Client(url)
    print client
    result = client.service.Login(nbiLogin NBILogin(username,password),)
    print result
```

i am unable to invoke the Login method, any idea how i can do this?

these are the methods returned by the query...

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( WsNBIService ) tns="www.test.com"
   Prefixes (1)
      ns0 = "www.test.com"
   Ports (1):
      (WsNBIPort)
         Methods (5):
            GetClientAssociationInfo(nbiSession NBISession, clientAssociationReqData ClientAssociationReqData, )
            GetEvent(nbiSession NBISession, eventReqData EventReqData, )
            GetZDClientAssociationInfo(nbiSession NBISession, clientAssociationReqData ClientAssociationReqData, )
            Login(nbiLogin NBILogin, )
            Logout(nbiSession NBISession, )
         Types (22):
            GetClientAssociationInfo
            GetClientAssociationInfoResponse
            GetEvent
            GetEventResponse
            GetZDClientAssociationInfo
            GetZDClientAssociationInfoResponse
            Login
            LoginResponse
            Logout
            LogoutResponse
            authenticateResult
            clientAssociationDetail
            clientAssociationReqData
            clientAssociationResult
            eventDetail
            eventReqData
            eventResult
            eventType
            nbiLogin
            nbiResult
            nbiSession
            requestType
```

**UPDATE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from suds.client import Client

def initialize():
    url = 'http://xxxxxxx/xxxx/WsNBI?wsdl'
    username = 'xxxxx'
    password = 'pppppp'
    client = Client(url)
    login = client.factory.create("ns0:NBILogin")
    print login
    ws = login.nbiLogin(userName=username, password = password)
    result = client.service.Login(ws)
    print result
def main():
    initialize()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


[root@server scripts]# ./flex_soap.py
(nbiLogin){
   UserName = None
   Password = None
 }
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./flex_soap.py", line 19, in ?
    main()
  File "./flex_soap.py", line 16, in main
    flexMaster()
  File "./flex_soap.py", line 12, in flexMaster
    ws = login.nbiLogin(userName=username, password = password)
AttributeError: nbiLogin instance has no attribute 'nbiLogin'
```

**UPDATE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from suds.client import Client

def initialize():
    url = 'http://xxxxx/intune/WsNBI?wsdl'
    username = 'uuuuu'
    password = 'pppp'
    client = Client(url)
    print client
    login = client.factory.create("ns0:NBILogin")
    print login
    login.UserName = username
    login.Password = password
    result = client.service.Login(login)
    print result
    event = client.factory.create("ns0:EventReqData")
    print event
def main():
    initialize()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

[root@server scripts]# ./flex_soap.py

(nbiLogin){
   UserName = None
   Password = None
 }
(authenticateResult){
   Success = True
   Session =
      (nbiSession){
         Id = "0eda1622-473c-4dd6-b68e-4ff3c1ee27f6"
      }
 }
(eventReqData){
   EventType =
      (eventType){
         value = None
      }
   SerialNumbers =
      (SerialNumbers){
         SerialNumber[] = <empty>
      }
 }
```

any idea how i can get this method

```
GetEvent(nbiSession NBISession, eventReqData EventReqData, )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not a valid Python. `Login(nbiLogin NBILogin, )` means that there is a method `Login` that accepts a single argument of type `NBILogin`. It is not a literal syntax that you should use. Try something like this:

```
 login = client.factory.create("ns0:NBILogin")
 login.UserName = username 
 login.Password = password 
 result = client.service.Login(login)
```

This output:

```
(authenticateResult){
   Success = True
   Session =
      (nbiSession){
         Id = "0eda1622-473c-4dd6-b68e-4ff3c1ee27f6"
      }
 }
```

means that `result.Success == True and result.Session.Id == "0eda1622-473c-4dd6-b68e-4ff3c1ee27f6"`.

`GetEvent(nbiSession NBISession, eventReqData EventReqData, )` means that you need 2 arguments of types `NBISession` and `EventReqData`.

The session you could get from `result`. To build `EventReqData`:

```
(eventReqData){
   EventType =
      (eventType){
         value = None
      }
   SerialNumbers =
      (SerialNumbers){
         SerialNumber[] = <empty>
      }
 }
```

you need to create `EventType` and `SerialNumbers`:

```
event_req_data = client.factory.create("ns0:EventReqData")
event_req_data.EventType = "put some appropriate event type here"
event_req_data.SerialNumbers = [10, 51, 1] # some serial numbers
```

The above assumes that serial numbers are integers otherwise create each `SerialNumber` the same way as all other objects via `client.factory.create()`:

```
sns = event_req_data.SerialNumbers = client.factory.create('ns0:SerialNumbers')
for item in [10, 51, 1]:
    ns = client.factory.create('ns0:SerialNumber')
    ns.value = item
    sns.SerialNumber.append(ns)
```

I don't see `SerialNumbers`, `SerialNumber` types in the listing so it might fail.

If suds doesn't convert from string to `EventType` by itself then you could create `EventType` using `client.factory.create()` explicitly:

```
event_type = client.factory.create("ns0:EventType")
event_type.value = "put some appropriate event type here"
event_req_data.EventType = event_type
```

Make the call:

```
event = client.service.GetEvent(login.Session, event_req_data)
```

Comment: thanks sebastian, i got some output, it now says "nbiLogin instance has no attribute 'nbiLogin'", sorry i am new to soap API's...also i printed how nbiLogin can be populated...any ideas?

Comment: @krisdigitx: I've update the answer to take into account info from `print login`.

Comment: thanks sebastian that worked, now i want to access the other method r "GetEvent(nbiSession NBISession, eventReqData EventReqData, )" any ideas? thanks for this really appreciate...i have attached the updated output...

Comment: hey sebastian, thanks a lot for me going, i can now get all events from the API...