# Python and PHP SOAP server

Tags: python, soap

I trying to use the SOAP service based on "PHP SOAP server". And I have a problem with the argument passing. When it's a scalar argument, all is OK, but when I try to pass the structure there is a failure. Python libraries create arrays in the different format. In this example I'm using the SUDS but the other libraries don't makes "right format" too.

Service WSDL: `http://www.drebedengi.ru/soap/dd.wsdl`

PHP query:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.drebedengi.ru/soap/dd.wsdl', array("trace" => 1));    
$client->getRecordList(
                'demo_api',
                'demo@example.com',
                'demo',
                array(
                     'is_report' => false,
                     'is_show_duty' => true,
                     'r_period' => 8,
                     'r_how' => 1,
                     'r_what' => 6,
                     'r_currency' => 0,
                     'r_is_place' => 0,
                     'r_is_tag' => 0,
                )
            )
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:ddengi"
                       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                       SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:getRecordList>
                <apiId xsi:type="xsd:string">demo_api</apiId>
                <login xsi:type="xsd:string">demo@example.com</login>
                <pass xsi:type="xsd:string">demo</pass>
                <params xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">is_report</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">is_show_duty</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">r_period</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:int">8</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">r_how</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">r_what</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:int">6</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">r_currency</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">r_is_place</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">r_is_tag</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</value>
                    </item>
                </params>
                <idList xsi:nil="true" />
            </ns1:getRecordList>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Python query with SUDS:

```py
client = suds.client.Client("http://www.drebedengi.ru/soap/dd.wsdl")
params = {
    "is_report": False,
    "is_show_duty": True,
    "r_period": 8,
    "r_how": 1,
    "r_what": 6,
    "r_currency": 0,
    "r_is_place": 0,
    "r_is_tag": 0
}
print client.service.getRecordList("demo_api", "demo@example.com", "demo", params)
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns4="urn:ddengi" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns4:getRecordList>
         <apiId xsi:type="ns2:string">demo_api</apiId>
         <login xsi:type="ns2:string">demo@example.com</login>
         <pass xsi:type="ns2:string">demo</pass>
         <params xsi:type="ns0:params">
            <is_report xsi:type="ns2:boolean">False</is_report>
            <r_how xsi:type="ns2:int">1</r_how>
            <r_currency xsi:type="ns2:int">0</r_currency>
            <is_show_duty xsi:type="ns2:boolean">True</is_show_duty>
            <r_is_tag xsi:type="ns2:int">0</r_is_tag>
            <r_is_place xsi:type="ns2:int">0</r_is_place>
            <r_what xsi:type="ns2:int">6</r_what>
            <r_period xsi:type="ns2:int">8</r_period>
         </params>
      </ns4:getRecordList>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried to use `client.factory.create()` but it doesn't work: types list is empty. There is the output of `print client`:

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( ddengiService ) tns="urn:ddengi"
   Prefixes (0)
   Ports (1):
      (SoapPort)
         Methods (28):
            deleteAll(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, )
            deleteObject(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:integer id, xs:string type, )
            getAccessStatus(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, )
            getAccumList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType idList, )
            getBalance(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType params, )
            getCategoryList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType idList, )
            getChangeList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:string revision, )
            getCurrencyList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType idList, )
            getCurrentRevision(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, )
            getExpireDate(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, )
            getOrderList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType idList, )
            getPlaceList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType idList, )
            getRecordList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType params, xs:anyType idList, )
            getRightAccess(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, )
            getServerSubs(xs:string url, )
            getSourceList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType idList, )
            getSubscriptionStatus(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, )
            getTagList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType idList, )
            getUserIdByLogin(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, )
            setAccumList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:string list, )
            setCategoryList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType list, )
            setCurrencyList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType list, )
            setPaymentTransaction(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:string transactionReceipt, xs:string amount, )
            setPlaceList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType list, )
            setRecordList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType list, )
            setSourceList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType list, )
            setTagList(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string pass, xs:anyType list, )
            userRegister(xs:string apiId, xs:string login, xs:string name, xs:string lang, )
         Types (0):
```

Comment: try to use `client.factory.create()` to create params. Here's [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11704155/4279)

Comment: I forget to tell: `client.factory.create()` doesn't work because the types list is empty. `print client` shows all the methods and 0 of types.

Comment: try `params = client.factory.create('{http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map')`

Comment: No, doesn't work. Finally I try this (doesn't work too):


`imp = Import('http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap')
client = suds.client.Client("http://www.drebedengi.ru/soap/dd.wsdl", plugins=[ImportDoctor(imp)])
params = client.factory.create('{http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map')`

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very descriptive. What is the code? What output does it produce?

Comment: Sorry. There is the logger trace:
`searching schema for ({http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map)
({http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map) not-found
path: "{http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map", not-found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/CryptoTracker/experiments.py", line 13, in <module>
    params = client.factory.create('{http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 234, in create
    raise TypeNotFound(name)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '{http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map'`

Comment: It seems `imp.filter.add("urn:ddengi")` is missing. Try to google [`suds.TypeNotFound`, it is a common error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4719854/4279).

Comment: I tried this too, nothing is changed. That returns the same error with the same trace.

`imp = Import('http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap')
imp.filter.add('urn:ddengi')
client = suds.client.Client("http://www.drebedengi.ru/soap/dd.wsdl", plugins=[ImportDoctor(imp)])
params = client.factory.create('{http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map')`

Comment: why haven't you set `location` explicitly as the link suggests?

Comment: I tried this. I set `location='http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap'` but this doesn't change anything. And `http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap` is not an existing document.

Comment: `localtion` should point to the schema (an actual xml file) where `Map` type is defined.

Comment: Unfortunately Google doesn't helps me with this quest. I think that Map is defined in the "http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" but it's not a real document. And where is the real document with the Map type, I didn't found.

Comment: related (unanswered): [How do I pass a map to a web service via SOAP in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13300473/4279)

Comment: if all else fails; use brute force: inject xml (from php client) as a request.

Comment: I found the solution. It's not a "clean" solution, but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the proper solution.
Main pain points are:

1. drebedengi.ru's WSDL does not import `http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap` nor `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/`. Those schemas are used, so they should be imported. This is fixed by `ImportDoctor`
2. `suds` library is rather old. I will use [suds-jurko 0.6](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds) as it seems to be more up to date. On the other hand, the same approach works for `suds 0.4`
3. `suds` knows nothing of `{http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map` data type. Thus there's no way to instantiate that. I work around that by adding my own schema definition for `xml-soap`. I have no clue what it should look like, however the way I declare it works fine for me.
4. drebedengi.ru sometimes prints `ns2:...` elements without declaring what `ns2` actually means. Of course they mean `http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap`.

The first thing is to teach `suds` to work with `Map` type:

```
from suds.store import defaultDocumentStore
from suds.xsd.sxbasic import Import as XsdImport

defaultDocumentStore.update({'xml.apache.org/xml-soap': \
"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" targetNamespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
      <xs:complexType name="Map">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="key" type='xs:anyType'/>
                 <xs:element name="value" type='xs:anyType'/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
"""})

XsdImport.bind(
    'http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap',
    'suds://xml.apache.org/xml-soap')
```

Then you need to add missing imports to the WSDL:

```
wsdl = 'http://www.drebedengi.ru/soap/dd.wsdl'
soapenc = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
soapenc.filter.add(None) # dd.wsdl does not have targetNamespace, thus None here
xmlsoap = Import('http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap')
xmlsoap.filter.add(None) # dd.wsdl does not have targetNamespace, thus None here
# NOTE: replace NoCache with the appropriate cache
client = Client(wsdl, cache=NoCache(), doctor=ImportDoctor(soapenc, xmlsoap))

# Sometimes responses reference ns2, so we declare it explicitly
client.add_prefix('ns2', 'http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap')
client.add_prefix('SOAP-ENC', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
```

Then you can instantiate that via `client.factory.create(...)`

```
raw_params = {
    "is_report": False,
    "is_show_duty": True,
    "r_period": 8,
    "r_how": 1,
    "r_what": 6,
    "r_currency": 0,
    "r_is_place": 0,
    "r_is_tag": 0
}

# Here we create the Map. Note how namespace is referenced
m = self.client.factory.create("{http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map")
m['item'] = [{"key": key, "value": params[key]} for key in params]
return client.service.getRecordList("demo_api", "demo@example.com", "demo", m)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [J. F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916433/adding-xsitype-and-envelope-namespace-when-using-suds/10977734#10977734) I found the solution:

```py
# coding=utf-8
import logging
import suds
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor


logger = logging.getLogger("suds.client")
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())


class SoapFixer(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        context.envelope.nsprefixes["ns4"] = "http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
        context.envelope.walk(self._fix_types)
        MessagePlugin.marshalled(self, context)

    def _fix_types(self, elem):
        for attr in elem.attributes:
            if attr.name == "type" and attr.value == "ns2:Array":
                attr.setValue("ns4:Map")


imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
client = suds.client.Client("http://www.drebedengi.ru/soap/dd.wsdl", doctor=ImportDoctor(imp), plugins=[SoapFixer()])

raw_params = {
    "is_report": False,
    "is_show_duty": True,
    "r_period": 8,
    "r_how": 1,
    "r_what": 6,
    "r_currency": 0,
    "r_is_place": 0,
    "r_is_tag": 0
}
array = client.factory.create("ns0:Array")
array["item"] = [{"key": key, "value": raw_params[key]} for key in raw_params]

print client.service.getRecordList("demo_api", "demo@example.com", "demo", array)
```

Comment: As you say, `SoapFixer` is fragile. It's better to use `{http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap}Map` directly (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41785546/1261287 )

Comment: Is it possible to do the same for Python 3? Code above doesn't work.